# Does every single value in a MySQL query have to be quoted?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

`insert_query = u"""
        INSERT INTO did_you_know (
        name, to_be_handled, creator, nominator, timestamp)
        VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}')
    """.format("whatever", "whatever", "whatever", "whatever", "whatever")` is my example.

Does every single value in a MySQL query have to contain quotes?

Would this be acceptable or not?
`INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('Hello', 1, 1, 0, 1, 'Goodbye')`

Thank you.

Comment: numeric values don't need to be quoted

Comment: @bansi In MySQL do any particular character need to be escaped?

Comment: yes you need to escape single quotes `'` otherwise how it it going to figure out where your string ends! check [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string‎) or try to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is NO.:) 
This is accepted: when the 'Hello' and 'Goodbye' is `Varchar` or text. and Numbers are integer or number type

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('Hello', 1, 1, 0, 1, 'Goodbye');
```

and in your example query is like.

```
insert_query = "
        INSERT INTO did_you_know(
        name,to_be_handled,creator,nominator,timestamp)
        VALUES('varchar_value', interger_or_number_value, 'varchar_value');
```

Like That . :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote only character and other non-integer data types.
Integer data types need not be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the standard practice in Python, you don't have to worry about escaping; and it will also prevent other nasty issues with your database.

Python has a standard DB API that all drivers conform to. In this API, to pass arguments to queries, you need to pass them to the execute function of the cursor *as a second argument*, not parse them in as a string (what you are doing).

Your query, correctly written will not have to worry about quoting at all:

```
q = """INSERT INTO did_you_know (
        name, to_be_handled, creator, nominator, timestamp)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

arg = "hello"
arg2 = "world"
cur.execute(q, ("foo","bar","zoo",arg,arg2,))
con.commit()
```

Keep in mind if you use any of MySQL's [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) as table names, you need to escape them in backticks.